# Share width between multiple elements dynamically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have a box in css whose horizontal space is shared by multiple elements. These elements should always use `100% width` of that element, unless they would collide, in which case they equally distribute the available width between all elements.

The below example shows 2 elements which share space in a container. When the blue one moves out of the red ones height, both should stretch to use 100% width again. I am using flexbox in this example, to show the intention of using `width: 100%` in the items. But if there is a solution that does not use flexbox, I would be happy to use that.

```css
html, body {
  background: gray;
}

.col {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  
  display: flex;
}

.col > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  
  top: 0px;
  
  animation: ani 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes ani {
  50% {
    top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

I am wondering if there is a pure-css solution for this.

Comment: but how the divs will move in reality? like you are showing?

Comment: Is the blue box going to be animated like that? And in which case the blue box should go to the next line? When the window reaches a certain width?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, similar to a calendar in e.g. Outlook, I would like elements to have a variable offset from the top. This offset might even be dynamically changeable by a user.  
@RamyAlayane The blue and red boxes should go back to `100% width` when the offset of the second box reaches `top: 50px`, because that would mean that they do not collide any longer.

Comment: It's hard to know the exact effects, e.g. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wExmgG

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for what purpose you need this to work, but if you have two divs and you want both div to 100% when second div reaches 50px then you should use animation for container as well.. I have created simple snippet below. Please let me know if it works for you!

```css
html, body {
  background: gray;
}

.col {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  animation: anicontainer 2s infinite;
}

.col > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  
  top: 0px;
  
  animation: ani 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes ani {
  50% {
    margin-top:-50px;
    top: 100px;
  }
}
@keyframes anicontainer {
  50% {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```